# How can we fit the chart on screen?

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I am using aChart Engine, Zoom in and out functionality in it moves the chart away from the screen.I want to keep the Chart fit to screen. Is there any way to keep the chart visible on screen i.e. always fit it to visible portion ??

I am using this method :

```
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getLineRenderer(int[] lineColor, PointStyle[] styles) {

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitle("Time");
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(15);
    renderer.setFitLegend(true);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    renderer.setYLabels(6);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(10);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(Common.min - 1);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(Common.max + 1);
    XYSeriesRenderer rendererSeries = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    rendererSeries.setColor(Color.RED);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererSeries);
    rendererSeries.setFillPoints(true);
    rendererSeries.setLineWidth(3);

    return renderer;
}
```

Comment: So you dont want zoom funtionality and fit your Chart in screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two things,

Either desable the Zoom functionality

`renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);`

or, Set Limits of for the Zoom

`renderer.setZoomLimits(arg0); // arg0 = new double[]{-20,20,-20,20}; anything you want`

Comment: it will simply disable zoom in out functionality,,but i dnt want this thing...I just want to stop my graph from scrolling...nd i found the solution,...

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution to my query

```
       renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
       renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
```

It works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can do either:

```
renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
```

or

```
renderer.setPanLimits(limits);
```